# Inline style via attribute mixin jade

Tags: html, css, node.js, pug

Is there any way of declaring a CSS width inline via a mixin attribute in Jade? An example of what I have tried is below...

```
mixin button(buttonLink, buttonText, buttonWidth)
 +link(buttonLink)(style='width:"buttonWidth"')
  font(style='color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;') 
   =buttonText
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible ;)

```
   mixin button(buttonLink, buttonText, buttonWidth)
     +link(buttonLink)(style="width:#{buttonWidth}")
       font(style='color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;') 
         =buttonText

    mixin link(buttonLink)
      a(src=buttonLink, style=attributes.style)
        block

    +button("http://github.com", "github", 10)
```

BTW: don't use `<font>`
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that! And only using the font tag due to Lotus notes not following the CSS set on the link (it's a HTML email, should have mentioned in the question!). Styling the font tag seems to fix it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

a little late, but this works as well!

```
mixin button(buttonLink, buttonText, buttonWidth)
  +link(buttonLink)(style='width:"'+buttonWidth+'"')
    font(style='color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;') 
      =buttonText
```