# Inline style width using attribute mixin jade

Tags: email, pug, html-email, mixins

I'm trying to do inline styling with jade mixins following the answer provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851294/inline-style-via-attribute-mixin-jade) but it doesn't work the way it is supossed to.

I'm using this jade:

```
mixin centerImg(margin,imgWidth,imgWidthpx,imgId)
table(border="0", cellpadding="0", cellspacing="0", width="640")
    tr
        td(width=margin)
        td(width=imgWidth)
            a.antiHand(href='#', style='cursor: none !important; pointer-events: none; border-style: none; border: none; border-color: transparent;')
                img(alt="", style="width:#{imgWidth};max-width:#{imgWidthpx};display:block;margin:0")(width=imgWidth)(src=imgId)
        td(width=margin)

+centerImg(200,240,"240px",'https://media.giphy.com/media/SzzNGHZWHCBqw/giphy.gif')
```

and this is what i get:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
          <tr>
            <td width="200"></td>
            <td width="240"><a class="antiHand" href="#" style="cursor: none !important; pointer-events: none; border-style: none; border: none; border-color: transparent;"><img alt="" style="width:#{imgWidth};max-width:#{imgWidthpx};display:block;margin:0" width="240" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/SzzNGHZWHCBqw/giphy.gif"/></a></td>
            <td width="200"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

any ideas?

Comment: The content of the mixin should be indented one level greater than the indentation level of the `mixin` declaration. Right now, you have them at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
style="width:#{imgWidth};max-width:#{imgWidthpx};display:block;margin:0"
```

Should change like this:

```
style=`width:${imgWidth};max-width:${imgWidthpx};display:block;margin:0`
```

I think this works!